# Is there any alternate method which is equivalent to setState metho(), that we can use for normal class other than a class with statefullWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am newbie to flutter. I am using the concept of **Asynchronous programming**. Flutter supports the concept of asynchronous through **async, await**. Whenever we use the above mentioned keywords **setState()** plays an important role for changing the values dynamically. I can use the Set state method only in the class with statefulwidget but not with any normal class ( without stateful widget )

**My primary goal** is to have all the asynchronous logic in a separate file and use/call it in the views of required widgets. This will reduce the code redundancy. So the code looks much more in refactored manner.

I need the expertd help to my problem.
This is my sample code
**ScreenTime.dart**

```
import 'package:app_usage/app_usage.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:installed_apps/installed_apps.dart';
import 'package:installed_apps/app_info.dart';


class ScreenTimeAlgorithm {
    List<AppUsageInfo> _usages = [];
    List<AppInfo> _apps = [];
    List<AppModel> _finalApps = [];
    late int totalScreenTime = 0;
    late int hr = 0, min = 0;

    void getStats() async {
    try {
      DateTime endTime = DateTime.now();

      int daySubtracter = endTime.hour;
      int minSubtracter = endTime.minute;
      int secSubtracter = endTime.second;
      DateTime startTime = endTime.subtract(
        Duration(
          hours: daySubtracter,
          minutes: minSubtracter,
          seconds: secSubtracter,
        ),
      );
      print(startTime); //00.00.00
      print(endTime); //14.47.23

      List<AppUsageInfo> usageList =
          await AppUsage.getAppUsage(startTime, endTime);
      List<AppInfo> apps = await InstalledApps.getInstalledApps(true, true);

      _finalApps = [];
      for (var app in apps) {
        for (var Usage in usageList) {
          if (app.packageName! == Usage.packageName) {
            var item = AppModel(
              title: app.name!,
              package: app.packageName!,
              icon: app.icon!,
              usagetime: Usage.usage.inMinutes,
            );
            _finalApps.add(item);
          }
        }
      }

      _finalApps.sort(
        (a, b) => b.usagetime.compareTo(a.usagetime),
      );

      for (var TTime in usageList) {
        totalScreenTime += TTime.usage.inMinutes;
      }
      setState(() {
        _usages = usageList;
        _apps = apps;
      });
    } on AppUsageException catch (exception) {
      print(exception);
    }
  }

}

class AppModel {
  final String title;
  final String package;
  final Uint8List icon;
  final int usagetime;
  late int hr = 0, min = 0;
  late String _formatTime = "";

  AppModel({
    required this.title,
    required this.package,
    required this.icon,
    required this.usagetime,
  });

  String timeFormatting() {
    if (usagetime != 0) {
      hr = (usagetime ~/ 60);
      min = usagetime % 60;
      if (hr == 0 || min == 0) {
        if (hr == 0 && min != 1) {
          _formatTime = '$min minutes';
        } else if (hr == 0 && min == 1) {
          _formatTime = '$min minute';
        } else if (hr != 1 && min == 0) {
          _formatTime = '$hr hours';
        } else if (hr == 1 && min == 0) {
          _formatTime = '$hr hour';
        } else {
          _formatTime = 'Less than 1 minute';
        }
      } else {
        if (hr == 1) {
          _formatTime = '$hr hour $min minutes';
        } else if (min == 1) {
          _formatTime = '$hr hours $min minute';
        } else {
          _formatTime = '$hr hours $min minutes';
        }
      }
    } else {
      _formatTime = "Less than one minute";
    }

    return _formatTime;
  }

  String get getTimeFormat {
    return timeFormatting();
  }
}
```

Since it is not a statefull widget it shows an error in setState() method. But without setState it always return the empty list of the desired await operations. What will be the approach to solve the problem? and What will be generalized way of doing with this kind of operations?

Answer (score 0):

since you are new to flutter, I strongly suggest you to read this:

https://github.com/infinum/flutter-dasher

This is excellent example of clean architecture made by Flutter expert.

There you can learn complete data flow and how to handle data after awaiting them.

Comment: Sure sir i will read this...